# How to write a SQL query to genenrate locality polygon tree structure with directions and level of adjacency?

Tags: query

If one has to write a SQL query which will accept locality polygon ID as input and generate output such that all First level or Direct adjacent polygon IDs are shown with respective direction(North-South-West-East) and if possible for second - third to last level.

for e.g.
embedded image of a cipy with each locality polygon given a unique ID; there is a table of data like

### id areaname areaonwest areaonsouth areaoneast areaonnorth

0  area0

1  area1

user could enter any ID and know which areas are directly adjacent to input Area polygon, which direction they are in and so on.

[image]

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).